# AngularJS request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: angularjs, json, http, post

Eempezando a utilizar Angular JS y necesito realizar una petición post a un servidor. La petición la estoy realizando de la siguiente manera:

```
var Informacion= JSON.parse('{"username":"--","password":"--"}')

$http.post('http://--:8080/taller-bd-11/usuarios/login', Informacion, {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

})
```

El problema es que al realizar la petición obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error en el navegador:

```
    LIVERELOAD: connecting to server  
    LIVERELOAD: successfully connected  
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load {url}. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

Por lo que entiendo es como si el objeto JSON que estoy enviando no estuviese en el formato JSON

Comment: Tienes tu URL, usuario, y contreseña en tu pregunta!!!!!!!  Nunca, pero nunca, hagas eso!  También, es mala forma incluir imágenes de código... mucho mejor poner el código directamente, como texto preformateado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No hay ningún problema con el formato del JSON.

El error ..

> Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

.. ocurre cuando el servidor no informa que admite el header `Content-Type` en una solicitud *Cross-Origin*. Esto es un feature de seguridad que ofrecen todos los navegadores, llamada [Política del Mismo Origen](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_del_mismo_origen). La intención de esta característica es evitar que puedas acceder a otro servidor utilizando `XMLHttpRequest` salvo que el segundo servidor lo *permita explicitamente* para tu sitio, metodo http y headers incluidos. Sin esto cualquier pagina que visites podría acceder a tu correo electrónico (por mencionar un ejemplo).

Si miras en la consola, veras que antes del error, el navegador envía una solicitud OPTIONS (conocida como  Preflight) y que en la respuesta no se incluye este header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

Como el servidor `pliskin12.ddns.net:8080` no envía en la respuesta al `OPTIONS` este header debido a su configuración de [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Preflight_example) (Cross-Origin-Resource-Share) el navegador interrumpe la solicitud, **no** envía el POST y muestra el error que ves.

Hay diferentes formas de *saltarse* la Política del mismo origen.

### Habilitar CORS

Habilitar *explicitamente* en el servidor `pliskin12.ddns.net:8080` el header `Content-Type`, como hacer esto depende del software de servidor utilizado. No es lo mismo configurarlo en IIS, NodeJs o Apache. Pero consiste en decirle al servidor que envié el header antedicho en la respuesta a `OPTIONS` (esto habilitara al navegador para enviar el POST)

Para habilitarlo debes ser (o tener acceso a un) administrador del servidor.

### Utilizar JSONP

En lugar de hacer una solicitud `XMLHttpRequest` puede utilizar [`JSONP`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). `JSONP` es una técnica concebida para suplir la limitación de AJAX entre dominios.

Para utilizar JSONP el servidor remoto debe soportarlo.

Un request JSONP se hace así en AngularJS: (notese callback=JSON_CALLBACK)

```
var url = 'pliskin12.ddns.net:8080/taller-db-11/usuarios/login?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';    
$http.jsonp(url).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // exito
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // error
    });
```

Ver la documentación de [`$http.jsonp`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) para angular.

### Conclusiones

Esto esta hecho para protegerte, pero cuando eres programador puede volverse un problema. Mi recomendacion es que intentes habilitar el header para CORS en el server, en segunda instancia que intentes JSONP.

Comment: Muy Buena respuesta, a mi me paso algo parecido pero no estaba seguro si esta era la solución era esta. Todos los días aprendemos y complementamos nuestro conocimiento.

Answer (score 0):

con respecto a tu comentario intenta mandar en `json` de esta manera

```
var Informacion = {
    "usename":"tuUsername",
    "password":"tuPassword"
};
```

Si no intenta realizarlo de esta otra manera:

```
// headers por default
$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 
    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
// envio de los datos
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://example.com/user/login',
    data: $.param({
        "username": "tuUsername",
        "password":" tuPass"
    }),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data)
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

espero que te funcione saludos.

nota: para usar `$.param({})` necesitas instanciar `JQuery`, lo puedes hacer copiando el `CDN` desde [aquí.](https://jquery.com/download/)